# How to know the values of every DataSet on JfreeChart Mouseover or Mouse Click envent

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to know how can i know the values of a curve(Dataset) when I standing over it on a XYPlot.

I've already implement the code for kwnoing the values of the scale on the axis:

```
    int mouseX = event.getTrigger().getX();
    int mouseY = event.getTrigger().getY();

    Point mousePoint = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);

    // convert the Java2D coordinate to axis coordinates...

    ChartRenderingInfo chartInfo = chart.getChartRenderingInfo();
    Point2D java2DPoint = chart.translateScreenToJava2D(mousePoint);
    PlotRenderingInfo plotInfo = chartInfo.getPlotInfo();

    Rectangle2D panelArea = chart.getScreenDataArea(mouseX, mouseY);

    double yy = Math.round(plot.getRangeAxis().java2DToValue(
            mousePoint.getY(), panelArea, plot.getRangeAxisEdge()));

    StringBuffer stringB = new StringBuffer();
    stringB.append("Profundidad : " + yy);

    // the x coordinate is the same for all subplots
    Rectangle2D dataArea = plotInfo.getDataArea();

    List<Long> curvas = pista.getCurvas();

    for (int i = 0, j = curvas.size(); i < j; i++) {
        if (curvas.get(i) != null) {
            double puntoXX = plot.getDomainAxis(i)
                    .java2DToValue(java2DPoint.getX(), dataArea,
                            plot.getDomainAxisEdge(i));

            double xx = (Math.ceil((puntoXX + 0.05d) * 100)) / 100;

            MDCurva curva = BuscadoresLista.buscarEnListaCurvas(curvas
                    .get(i));
            stringB.append(" " + curva.getNombreCurva() + " " + xx);
        }
    }

    PBarraEstado.getInstance().getTextoSubEstado2().setText(
            stringB.toString());
```

but, now i want to know the value of every curva in the plot.
can anywone help me with that

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with the [examples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) found under `Miscellaneous > Crosshairs` in the [`JFreeChart Demo`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp).